# JQuery display checkboxed table row data

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, checkbox, html-table

So I know there are a few posts about this but I haven't found them to helpful so I'm hoping this will shed new light on my problem.

I'm trying to to get data from a check-boxed row in a HTML table. At the moment I only want to display it on a `windows.alert` or in the Visual Studio console. But eventually I'm going to post the data to a database.

My code:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('#button').click(function () {
        var id = [];
        $(':checkbox:checked').each(function (i) {
            id[i] = $(this).val();
        });
        if (id.length === 0) {
            alert("Please select at least one checkbox");
        }
        else {
            $.post('http://localhost/Dynamic/?Insert');
        }
    });
});
```

I've tried `alert($(this).text())` but that just appears empty.

Help would be appreciated.

If it helps this is how I populate the table:

```
var tableName = 'table1'
$.ajax({
        url: 'http://localhost/Dynamic?prod=' + tableName,
        dataType: 'Json',
        success: function (Results) {
            $.each(Results, function () {
                var row = "";
                for (i = 0; i < this.length; i++) {
                var input = '<td>' + this[i] + '</td>';
                row = row + input;
                }

                $('#table1 tbody:last-child').append('<tr>' + row + '<td> <input class="checkBox" type="checkbox" id="count"/> </td></tr>');
            });
        }                                   
    });
```

As you can see the table is populated dynamically so it can be populated by different tables.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've gotten it to work, I created a global array and added all the values to that. I then created a counter and set each checkbox's ID to the counters value. I then increment the counter before looping back around to sort with the next row of data.

Then When I want to choose data. I check the checkbox's of the data. Press the button then I get the Id's of each of the checkbox's. I then put the checkbox id into the array to get the value before adding it to an array which I then post.

Answer (score 0):

your selector is wrong. $(':checkbox:checked') should be  $('.checkbox:checked').
maybe try to change to different class name.

```
$('.mycheckbox:checked').each(function (i) {
        id[i] = $(this).val();
    });
```

Comment: No it's correct. I tried with the colon and fullstop and only colon worked.

Comment: where is your i declare under your each statement.

Comment: try this in your assign statement  `code` id.push($(this).val()); `code`

Comment: Will do, can't right now, computer lab closed till Monday :(

Comment: I've tried it and displayed the result on the console and all I get is the word "on". None of my data contains on. Any suggestions?

Comment: can you attach your html too.